# How to define default date values in Symfony2 routes?

Tags: symfony, routes

If I want to create a route, where the year, month and date are variables, how can I define that if these variables are empty, the current date shall be taken?

E.g. like this (doesn't work for sure...)

```
blog:
    path:      /blog/{year}/{month}/{day}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index,
                    year:  current_year,
                    month: current_month
                    day:   current_day
               }
```

I thought about defining two different routes, like this

```
blog_current_day:
    path:      /blog
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index }

blog:
    path:      /blog/{year}/{month}/{day}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index }
```

But if I then call `blog_current_day` my controller

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $year, $month, $day) {
    // ...
}
```

will throw an exception because year, month and day are missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hope my answer contains what you've been looking for :) nice blog btw - greetings from cologne.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Dynamic Container Parameters

You can set [container parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) dynamically in your bundle's extension located `Acme\BlogBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeBlogExtension` afterwards you can use those parameters in your routes like `%parameter%`.

### Extension

```
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AcmeBlogExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->setParameter(
            'current_year',
            date("Y")
        );

        $container->setParameter(
            'current_month',
            date("m")
        );

        $container->setParameter(
            'current_day',
            date("d")
        );
    }
}
```

### Routing Configuration

```
blog:
    path:      /blog/{year}/{month}/{day}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, year: %current_year%, month: %current_month%, day: %current_day% }
```

### Static Parameters

If you only need configurable static parameters you can just add them to your `config.yml`.

```
parameters:
    static_parameter: "whatever"
```

... then again access them in your routing like `%static_parameter%`.

Comment: Wow, this is the ninja way! This answer is actually more precisely answering my question. But I just needed *one* way, as @Igor's seems easier, I think I'll take that one.

Comment: Revert: I'll take this one! :-)

Comment: The class has to be Vendor**NameWithoutBundle**Extension living in the `DependencyInjection` folder to be autoloaded.

Comment: Is there a certain nomenclature I have to follow when naming my extension? Or do I have to register it anywhere? Because right now I am getting `You have requested a non-existent parameter "current_year"`.

Comment: did you clear your cache? Read documentation chapter [Creating an Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class) - especially [Extension Conventions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#extension-conventions) explains how to register extensions and the naming conventions for autoloading. I tested the example above using symfony 2.1,2.2 & 2.3 prior to posting it. quick n' dirty: you could add a simple `die('extension loaded!')` in the extension's `load(..)` method to check wether it's being loaded.

Comment: @nfir, curious behaviour: I called that route again today and takes a wrong day value (`date('d')` gave out `16` instead of `17`). What is wrong here and how can I assure that **always** the proper value is taken?

Comment: the reason for this should be a timezone setting / server time setting. double-check if there are any differences between `date()` output and the current time you're expecting :)

Comment: That is impossible; it was around 11 am when I discovered this error. Plus: When I edited that file (I did a `die()` in there to debug) and saved it again, the error disappeared.

Comment: Note: This wasn't an error of one **hour**, but of one **day**!

Comment: quoting a wise man: *The cache, the cache, the good old cache...*  there are two possibilities - date() returning the wrong timetamp and the second one would be the routing cache holding an outdated version of the routing configuration. In the second case you might want to consider a cronjob clearing/re-warming your (routing)-cache at midnight.

Comment: Oh damn... but wouldn't that mean that the cache is emptied each day?

Comment: you could create a command that only updates this one cached route. or maybe consider using a kernel event listener that newly registers the route on every request if you can afford the performance impact.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I have created a new question as an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866969/how-to-update-specific-cached-route) to your last comment to not comment flood your answer here :-)

Comment: It is important to note that the `Extension::load` is only called during the `Kernel::buildContainer` generally called with `cache:warmup`. This will result in static date values at the point the Symfony container is built in `var/cache/` or until the container is rebuilt.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `$year = null, $month = null, $day = null` in controller.

or maybe in route:

```
year:  null,
month: null,
day:   null,
```

Then in controller you should get last posts if variables = null, or posts by date.

Comment: he is looking for route defaults Igor in this case - please see my answer :)