# Restrict access to pages depending on date

Tags: symfony

I would like to restrict access to pages depending on a date store in my data base. For example, I would like that all the route after: monsite.fr/mon_compte/ check a condition of date. I just wondering if there is a better way with symfony2 to do that ?

Ty in advance :)

Comment: Have a look to the @nifr answer concerning a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781708/how-to-define-default-date-values-in-symfony2-routes

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like that :

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $dates = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:DateAce')->getAuthorizationDate($user->getId());

    $now = new DateTime();

    if($dates->debut() < $now < $dates->fin())
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException;
    }

}
```